# ASP.NET Web Api HttpClient.GetAsync with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Web Api method signature

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage GetGroups(MyRequest myRequest)
```

In the client, how do I pass MyRequest to the calling method?

Currently, I have something like this

```cs
var request = new MyRequest()
{
    RequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
};

var response = client.GetAsync("api/groups").Result;
```

How can I pass `request` to `GetAsync`?

If it's a `POST` method, I can do something like this

```cs
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/groups", request).Result;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot send a message body for HTTP GET requests and for that reason, you cannot do the same using `HttpClient`. However, you can use the URI path and the query string in the request message to pass data. For example, you can have a URI like `api/groups/12345?firstname=bill&lastname=Lloyd` and the parameter class `MyRequest` like this.

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Since `MyRequest` is a complex type, you have to specify model binding like this.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetGroups([FromUri]MyRequest myRequest)
```

Now, the `MyRequest` parameter will contain the values from the URI path and the query string. In this case, `Id` will be 12345, `FirstName` will be bill and `LastName` will be Lloyd.